# Error on Enabling kong api gateway prometheus plugin in Docker

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I configured prometheus plugin in my kong declarative config file using the below configuration, but getting the error when I run it on kong docker image.

error:

```
Error: 
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/config.lua:110: Failed parsing:
in 'plugins':
  - in entry 4 of 'plugins':
    in 'config':
      in 'latency_metrics': unknown field
      in 'bandwidth_metrics': unknown field
      in 'status_code_metrics': unknown field
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/config.lua:110: in function 'cmd_exec'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:88: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:45>
        /usr/local/bin/kong:9: in function 'file_gen'
        init_worker_by_lua:49: in function <init_worker_by_lua:47>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        init_worker_by_lua:56: in function <init_worker_by_lua:54>
```

Configuration on declarative yaml

```
  - name: prometheus
    config:
      bandwidth_metrics: true
      latency_metrics: true
      status_code_metrics: true
```

Docker image : kong:2.1.1

Greatly appreciate if anyone can give me a help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: The error arises from your Kong's image version: `Docker image : kong:2.1.1`. 
For this version, enabling the plugin itself is enough to export all the metrics, if you want to export metrics separated by consumers, use `config.per_consumer: true`.
[Here](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/prometheus/2.1.x.html)  is the Prometheus plugin referencefor kong version 2.1.x

Up until 2.8.x (2.8.x downward), The Prometheus plugin only has 4 configs: `name`, `service.name/service.id`, `enabled`, and, `config.per_consumer`. The first three is to enable the plugin itself while the latter make Prometheus plugin export metrics with consumer in mind,

When Kong [3.0.0 released](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/changelog/#3000), They made Prometheus plugin to has all cardinality metrics disabled by default, hence the need to configure `bandwidth_metrics`, `latency_metrics`, `status_code_metrics`, and so on.